# Update multiple rows based on other table column values

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the query I have so far and I understand WHY it isn't working... Just having a hard time forming a solution.

```
UPDATE wrkque
SET locacc = (SELECT locmst.locacc
            FROM locmst,
                 wrkque
           WHERE locmst.stoloc = wrkque.srcloc
             AND wrkque.oprcod = 'TRN')
WHERE wrkque.oprcod = 'TRN'
AND wrkque.srcloc IN (SELECT locmst.stoloc
                        FROM locmst,
                             wrkque
                       WHERE locmst.stoloc = wrkque.srcloc)
```

The inner query returns multiple rows. I believe I need to do a partition by type query but a tad unsure.

Essentially, I need to update the wrkque table so that all row instances that are of "TRN" (Transfers) are updated to reflect the "locacc" (Location Access) from the locmst table.

The key to linking both tables rows to eachother is locmst.stoloc and wrkque.srcloc.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE wrkque
SET    locacc = (SELECT locmst.locacc
                 FROM   locmst
                 WHERE  locmst.stoloc = wrkque.srcloc)
WHERE  wrkque.oprcod = 'TRN'
```

The inner query needs to be referenced to the outer query, which we're doing here: `WHERE locmst.stoloc = wrkque.srcloc`.  We don't need the join inside the inner query, we simply need the reference.

**Edit for EXISTS:**

As Gordon points out in his answer, you should include an `EXISTS` correlation clause in the outer query as well:

```
UPDATE wrkque
SET    locacc = (SELECT locmst.locacc
                 FROM   locmst
                 WHERE  locmst.stoloc = wrkque.srcloc)
WHERE  wrkque.oprcod = 'TRN'
AND EXISTS (SELECT locmst.stoloc
            FROM   locmst
            WHERE  locmst.stoloc = wrkque.srcloc)
```

Without this, any rows that do not meet `locmst.stoloc = wrkque.srcloc` (exist in `wrkque` but not in `locmst`) will have `locacc` set to `null`.  If every row exists in both tables, you can leave it out, but it's better practice to always include it.

Comment: Sheesh, thanks Aaron. Lets just say I was over thinking this one... lol

Answer (score 2):

These types of updates are tricky.  Your fundamental problem is that you have a `join` in the subquery when you should be using a correlation clause.  You need to do this both for the `set` and the `where`:

```
UPDATE wrkque
    SET locacc = (SELECT locmst.locacc
                  FROM locmst
                  WHERE locmst.stoloc = wrkque.srcloc
                 )
    WHERE wrkque.oprcod = 'TRN' AND
          EXISTS (SELECT locmst.stoloc
                  FROM locmst
                  WHERE locmst.stoloc = wrkque.srcloc 
                 );
```

Having said that, why are you storing `locacc` in the `wrkque` table?  You can always fetch the appropriate value using `join`.  There are good reasons for doing this, such as you might be initializing the value and then it gets overwritten.  In most cases, though, there is no need to store the same information in two places.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE (SELECT locmst.locacc newOne, wrkque.locacc oldOne
            FROM locmst, wrkque
           WHERE locmst.stoloc = wrkque.srcloc
             AND wrkque.oprcod = 'TRN') t 
SET t.oldOne = t.newOne;
```